# primera limpieza de un dataframe usando pandas,regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe

Estoy trabajando en mi primer proyecto de limpieza de base de datos,y la verdad que me siento un poco perdida y no sé bien por dónde empezar.

Quizás creo que es mejor empezar creando un dataframe nuevo a partir del anterior ya que solo me interesa trabajar con ciertas columnas, estoy probando con este código, pero no parece ser el correcto:

```
df2=df['Date','Country','Activity','Genre','Age','Species','Source']
```

Una vez hecho esto sustituyo los espacios en blanco que haya en cada columna por **dato_desconocido**, aquí necesito usar regex,pero no sé muy bien como usarlo, ¿alguna idea?

Comment: Hola ¿A qué te refieres con espacios en blanco? ¿Columnas con cadenas vacías?¿Columnas que tiene cadenas con espacios? Si es ésta última, ¿se sustituyen todos?¿solo algunos?¿bajo que condiciones?¿todos por el mismo carácter o dependiendo de alguna condición el carácter de reemplazo varía? Por favor agrega un [mcve] que contemple todas las posibilidades y el resultado esperado, las variables son muchas. El uso de regex puede o no puede ser necesario o la mejor opción, dependerá del resultado que busques.

Answer (score 2):

tienes algunos errores. En primer lugar, deberías haber usado:

```
df2 = df[['Date','Country','Activity','Genre','Age','Species','Source']]
```

De tal forma que df2 tome un valor de un DataFrame, lo otro, no existe. Cuando usas un solo índice, estás seleccionando una serie

Luego, para llenar los campos vacíos, **no** requieres `regex`, hay una función en Pandas que se llama `fillna()` y la usarías de esta forma:

```
df2.fillna('dato_desconocido', inplace=True)
```

Aunque, no creo que sea lo mejor. Creo que es mejor que lo dejes como NaN, sobre todo si vas a hacer cálculos sobre esa columna, a lo mejor valdría la pena que buscaras completar esos datos de otra forma, quizás asignándoles la media de la columna, o la mediana, o un valor por defecto, no sé... depende de lo que estés haciendo.

Comment: Muchas gracias!!